# Weird Training Issue with keras - sudden huge drop in loss with zeros in FC layer

Tags: keras

I'm getting this odd issue with training a siamese-style CNN with Keras (backend of Tensor Flow, Ubuntu 14.04, Cuda 8, with cudnn). In short, the CNN has a shared set of weights that takes in two images, merges their respective FC layers, and then estimates a regression.  I'm using MSE loss with the Adam optimizer (with default parameters).  I've done this several times with different types of problems and have never seen the following.

Essentially what happens is on the first epoch, everything seems to be training fine, and the loss is decreasing slowly, as expected (ends at around an MSE of ~3.3 using a batch size of 32). The regression is estimating a 9-dimensional continuous-valued vector.

Then, as soon as the second epoch starts, the loss drops DRAMATICALLY (to ~ 4e-07).  You'd think "oh yay the loss is really small--I win", but when I inspect the trained weights by prediction on novel inputs (I'm using the checkpointer to dump out the best set of weights according to the loss), I get odd behavior.  No matter what the inputs are (different images, random noise as inputs, even zeros), I always get the same exact output.  Further inspection shows that the last FC layer in the shared weights are all zeros.

If I look at the weights after the first epoch, when everything seems "normal", this doesn't happen--I just don't get optimal results (makes sense--only one epoch has occurred).  This only happens with the second epoch and on.

Has anybody ever seen this?  Any ideas?  You think it's a dumb error on my part, or some weird bug?

More details on my network topology here.  Here are the shared weights:

```
shared_model = Sequential()

shared_model.add(Convolution2D(nb_filter=96, nb_row=9, nb_col=9, activation='relu', subsample=(2,2), input_shape=(3,height,width)))
shared_model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2,2)))
shared_model.add(Convolution2D(nb_filter=256, nb_row=3, nb_col=3, activation='relu', subsample=(2,2)))
shared_model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2,2)))
shared_model.add(Convolution2D(nb_filter=256, nb_row=3, nb_col=3, activation='relu'))
shared_model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2,2)))
shared_model.add(Convolution2D(nb_filter=512, nb_row=3, nb_col=3, activation='relu', subsample=(1,1)))

shared_model.add(Flatten())

shared_model.add(Dense(2048, activation='relu'))
shared_model.add(Dropout(0.5))
```

Then I merge them for regression as follows:

```
input_1 = Input(shape=(3,height,width))
input_2 = Input(shape=(3,height,width))
encoded_1 = shared_model(input_1)
encoded_2 = shared_model(input_2)
encoded_merged = merge([encoded_1, encoded_2], mode='concat', concat_axis=-1)
fc_H = Dense(9, activation='linear')
h_loss = fc_H(encoded_merged)
model = Model(input=[input_1, input_2], output=h_loss)
```

Finally, each epoch trains on about 1,000,000 samples, so there should be plenty of data to train.  I've just never seen a FC layer get set to all zeros.  And even at that, I don't understand how that makes for a very low loss when the training data are not all zeros.

Answer (score 0):

For the zeroes which are seemingly getting predicted by the last layer what might have happened is the dying ReLU problem. Try LeakyReLU, tweak alpha. This worked for me in eradicating those zeros which I would get in the first epoch itself.